# How to access a methodB variable value from methodA

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 button events. When I click `button1`, I am calling (by passing some values) `methodA` where I am dynamically creating an array of checkboxes and an array.

Now if I click `button2`, I should be able to get the values which I have set while clicking `button1` (checkbox array and array values). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create an object to store your values. Store the values in the `ViewState`.

Answer (score 0):

Make that as global variable for class.

Declare those in class scope

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could store your array into `Session` or maybe the `ViewState` in first button click.Retrieve the same in the other button click

Answer (score 0):

Store the values in `ViewState` from function1, you could retrieve that value from function B, for example,

```
Session["myData"] = "Hello World";///storing in session

string str = (string)Session["myData"];///retrieving from session
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

> ViewState["variable"] = [Object]